# why php write empty lines into text file?

Tags: php

I had a form which checkboxes that post selected rows to $_POST['select'][$i] array that used in select data from db.
the result from sql is used to write the result into text file with newline but only write the first line and others are empty lines.
please help.
my code below.

```
<?php 

    $rowCountd = count($_POST["select"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$rowCountd;$i++) {

        $rowwd=$_POST['select'][$i]; 

        $path_stu_test = $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'].'\Documents\performance/student_test.txt';

        $file_stu_test = fopen($path_stu_test, 'w');    

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT row_no, adms_no, full_name from stu_perform where row_no= :rowwd1');

        $stmt->bindParam(':rowwd1', $postrowwd1, SQLITE3_TEXT); $postrowwd1 = $rowwd;
        $ret = $stmt->execute(); 

        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){

            $adms_not = $row['adms_no'];
            $full_namet = $row['full_name'];
            $file2 = "$adms_not~$full_namet\r\n";
            fwrite($file_stu_test, $file2);

        }
    }
?>
```

I think the problem is the way I used fwrite inside for() loop with While(){} block because the code below works i.e it display write all the sql result

```
<?php

    $rowwd = 02;
    $path_stu_test = $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'].'\Documents\performance/student_test.txt';

    $file_stu_test = fopen($path_stu_test, 'w');

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT row_no, adms_no, full_name from stu_perform where row_no= :rowwd1');

    $stmt->bindParam(':rowwd1', $postrowwd1, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $postrowwd1 = $rowwd;
    $ret = $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){

        $adms_not = $row['adms_no'];
        $full_namet = $row['full_name'];

        $file2 = "$adms_not~$full_namet\r\n";
        fwrite($file_stu_test, $file2);

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why not searching for all rows in one query, and then save/write the returned array of data into the file instead of querying each single line/entry you want to have?

Comment: Thank for you quick respond. I need to let users select their prefer data before I can use that to write to text file. Though if I could presume users selection like $rowwd = 02; in my example code 2, it will work. pls any further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches - neither tested btw. One thing I note in the original code is the manner in which the prepared statement is created - namely inside the loop. One of the beauties and power of a prepared statement is that you should create it once but execute multiple times ~ so the first example below prepares the query outside the loop and executes multiple times inside the loop using a different value from the array each increment.

```
<?php 

    if( !empty( $_POST['select'] ) ){

        $bytes=array();
        $count=count( $_POST['select'] );
        $outputfile=sprintf( '%s/Documents/performance/student_test.txt', $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'] );

        $sql='select `row_no`, `adms_no`, `full_name` from `stu_perform` where `row_no`=:id;';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $id, SQLITE3_TEXT );

            for( $i=0; $i < $count; $i++ ){

                $id = $_POST['select'][ $i ];
                $result = $stmt->execute();

                if( $result ){
                    while( $rs=$result->fetchArray( SQLITE3_ASSOC ) ){
                        $data = sprintf( '%s~%s', $rs['adms_no'], $rs['full_name'] );
                        $bytes[]=file_put_contents( $outputfile, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
                    }
                }
            }

            if( !empty( $bytes ) ) printf( '%d entries and %s bytes written to file',count( $bytes ), array_sum( $bytes ) );

        }
    }
?>
```

Rather than executing multiple times you can in many database engines use the `in` keyword ( ie `select * from tbl where id in (1,2,3,99)` etc )

```
<?php 

    if( !empty( $_POST['select'] ) ){

        $bytes=array();
        $count=count( $_POST['select'] );
        $outputfile=sprintf( '%s/Documents/performance/student_test.txt', $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'] );

        $sql='select `row_no`, `adms_no`, `full_name` from `stu_perform` where `row_no` in ( :ids );';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bindParam( ':ids', $ids, SQLITE3_TEXT );
            $ids = implode( ',', $_POST['select'] );

            $result = $stmt->execute();

            if( $result ){
                while( $rs=$result->fetchArray( SQLITE3_ASSOC ) ){
                    $data = sprintf( '%s~%s', $rs['adms_no'], $rs['full_name'] );
                    $bytes[]=file_put_contents( $outputfile, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
                }
            }


            if( !empty( $bytes ) ) printf( '%d entries and %s bytes written to file', count( $bytes ), array_sum( $bytes ) );

        }
    }
?>
```

---

As a quick demo to test the above I put the following together having read your comment. This is clearly pertinent to my system and databases ( mysql ) but follows closely the logic of the above

```
<?php
    $field='select';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        require 'pdoconn.php';

        $file=__DIR__ . '/tmp-output.txt';
        $bytes=array();

        $sql='select * from `city` where `id`=:id';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            foreach( $_POST[ $field ] as $index => $id ){
                $stmt->execute();
                while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
                    $bytes[]=file_put_contents( $file, sprintf( 'ID:%d, Name:%s, Country Code:%s, District: %s', $rs->ID, $rs->Name,$rs->CountryCode,$rs->District ) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>multi-checkboxes - read from db, write to text file</title>
        <style>
            form{width:50%;float:none;margin:5rem auto 0 auto;}
            label{display:inline-block;margin:1rem auto;float:none;width:20%;text-align:center;border:1px dotted gray;box-sizing:border-box;}
            input[type='submit']{width:100%;padding:1rem;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <?php
                for( $i=1; $i <= 25; $i++ ){

                    $checked = rand(0,1) == 1 ? 'checked' : '';
                    $br = $i > 0 && $i % 5==0 ? '<br />' : '';

                    /* assume that the valud is equal to the ID of whatever record .... */
                    printf( '<label>%s<input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="%d" %s /></label>%s', sprintf( 'Item: %d', $i ), $i, $checked, $br );
                }
                if( !empty( $bytes ) ) printf( '<p>%d entries and %s bytes written to file</p>',count( $bytes ), array_sum( $bytes ) );
            ?>
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

--

[image: Before submitting the form]
This shows the random selection of checkboxes made prior to submitting the form

[image: After submitting the form]
This shows the data written to the file after the form has been submitted. Check the IDs in the 2nd image correspond to the selected checkboxes in the first image ( though I realise you can't see them all )

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider, the your first code works for me with a issue, it doesn't write to file all the result . why is it always omit the next result e.g if the result fetch a, b, c, d, e, f  when I echo it within while block it will display all accordingly, but only write to text file a, c, e only. I have tried to fixed it but couldn't. pls help

Comment: @ RamRaider  Thanks a lot, I learnt from all the sample codes and comments. It works.

Comment: Good - I'm glad that the examples helped progress your own coding adventures ;-)